# How does systemctl variable escaping work in a shell?

Tags: bash, systemd, systemctl, variables

I want do a batch job with systemctl, something like:

`systemctl status v2ray-haproxy@{1..5}`

That's fine. But when i change 5 to a variable：

`n=5;systemctl status v2ray-haproxy@{1..$n}`

It's not working now, and error:

> Invalid unit name "v2ray-haproxy@{1..5}" was escaped as "v2ray-haproxy@\x7b1..5\x7d" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
>   Unit v2ray-haproxy@\x7b1..5\x7d.service could not be found.

How to get this variable code work?

Comment: You might want to remove systemctl from the title - as this is a bash question.

Comment: This is a cross-site duplicate of ["Brace expansion with variable?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432753/brace-expansion-with-variable) (and many others) on stackoverflow.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks, `n=5;for i in $(seq 1 $n); systemctl status v2ray-haproxy@$i; done`  working!

Answer (score 0):

try something like below

```
n=5;systemctl status v2ray-haproxy@{1..$(seq 1 $n)}
```

Comment: not work: `Failed to get unit for PID 2: PID 2 does not belong to any loaded unit.
Failed to get unit for PID 3: PID 3 does not belong to any loaded unit.
Failed to get unit for PID 4: PID 4 does not belong to any loaded unit.
Invalid unit name "v2ray-haproxy@{1..1" was escaped as "v2ray-haproxy@\x7b1..1" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
Invalid unit name "5}" was escaped as "5\x7d" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
Unit 5\x7d.service could not be found.`